# Monitor or record a robocopy operation

Tags: backup, robocopy

I have a robocopy command that backs up a folder containing over 200K files into another folder called Backup. Lately, I notice that the backup is now taking additional 1hr to complete even though the folder contents only changed by 100kb.

Is there a way I can record how long it takes for each files in the folder to be backed up.

> The robocopy command was already built into an application. I need
>   something that I can run during the time when the robocopy operation
>   starts so I can capture the time between each file backup and NOT the
>   over time it took for the backup to complete

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using the `/log` [switch](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx) will give you a start and end time. e.g.

[image]

Comment: Sorry I should have been clear on this. The command was already built into an application but without the /log switch. So i need something that I can run during the time when the robocopy operation starts so i can capture the time

Comment: Seen your screenshot, the time bit is the overall time it took to complete the backup. That's not what i need. I need time between each file backup

Comment: @Chelseawillrecover so you want the time it takes for every file AND you can't use **any switches**?

Comment: @Chelseawillrecover sounds to me like you're hacking a fix instead of fixing the issue! Update the application to accept a parameter to receive switches

Comment: No this is not a HACK. An application was written few years ago and I am inheriting this and ending up with some delays. So no way to recode this APP. All I am hoping to do is record each files been backed up and time it takes to do the backup since I can't edit the code.